# Map location returning null for android

Tags: android, google-maps

My getLastKnownLocation is turning up "null".  I can get the locations I put in to show however get the users location has been trying.  From the docs, here, and 4 05 tutorials I thought I was doing it right, but...... I'm not.  I just cannot seem to figure out why.

If someone has a sec to look this over that would be great.

```
package com.kita.Maps;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.MailTo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity  implements LocationListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

MapView map;
private MyLocationOverlay me = null;
Drawable d;
List<Overlay> overlayList;
LocationManager lm;
String towers;
int lat;
int longi;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.myMain);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    Touchy t = new Touchy();
    overlayList = map.getOverlays();
    overlayList.add(t);

    map.getController().setCenter(
            getPoint(40.76793169992044, -73.98180484771729));
    map.getController().setZoom(17);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    Drawable marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_yellow);

    marker.setBounds(0, 0, marker.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            marker.getIntrinsicHeight());

    map.getOverlays().add(new SitesOverlay(marker));

    me = new MyLocationOverlay(this, map);
    map.getOverlays().add(me);

    d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_blue);

    //  Geo Location of phone
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria crit = new Criteria();
    towers = lm.getBestProvider(crit, false);
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(towers);

    if(location != null){
        lat = (int) (location.getLatitude()*1E6);
        longi = (int) (location.getLongitude()*1E6);
        GeoPoint ourLocation = new GeoPoint(lat, longi);
        OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(ourLocation, "Quit hitting your self","");
        CustomPinpoint custom = new CustomPinpoint(d, MapsActivity.this);
        custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
        overlayList.add(custom);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Couldn't get provider", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    me.enableCompass();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(towers, 500, 1, this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    me.disableCompass();
    lm.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

class Touchy extends Overlay {
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView m) {

        return false;
    }
}

private GeoPoint getPoint(double lat, double lon) {
    return (new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1000000.0), (int) (lon * 1000000.0)));
}

private class SitesOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    private List<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    public SitesOverlay(Drawable marker) {
        super(marker);

        boundCenterBottom(marker);

        items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(40.748963847316034,
                -73.96807193756104), "UN", "United Nations"));
        items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(40.76866299974387,
                -73.98268461227417), "Lincoln Center",
                "Home of Jazz at Lincoln Center"));
        items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(40.765136435316755,
                -73.97989511489868), "Carnegie Hall",
                "Where you go with practice, practice, practice"));
        items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(40.70686417491799,
                -74.01572942733765), "The Downtown Club",
                "Original home of the Heisman Trophy"));

        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return (items.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, items.get(i).getSnippet(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return (true);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return (items.size());
    }
}



public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    lat = (int) (l.getLatitude() *1E6);
    longi = (int) (l.getLongitude()*1E6);
    GeoPoint ourLocation = new GeoPoint(lat, longi);
    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(ourLocation, "Quit hitting your self","");
    CustomPinpoint custom = new CustomPinpoint(d, MapsActivity.this);
    custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
    overlayList.add(custom);
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Here is my custom pointer class:

```
package com.kita.Maps;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class CustomPinpoint extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>{

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> pinpoints = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private Context c;


public CustomPinpoint(Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(boundCenter(defaultMarker));
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomPinpoint(Drawable m, Context context) {        
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this(m);
    c = context;
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pinpoints.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pinpoints.size();
}

public void insertPinpoint(OverlayItem item){
    pinpoints.add(item);
    this.populate();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getLastKnownLocation, try requestLocationUpdates. You can use a LocationListener to listen for location updates. More info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html

Answer (score 1):

getLastKnownLocation gives nulls, a lot, it's just the nature of the beast.

Use a [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) and wait if you want to secure a solid position.  getLastKnownLocation is really only good for priming location based logic being feed by a LocationListener.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I gave the check to Ben because mentioning "requestLocationUpdates" led me to the best answer for my overall app.   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking whats going on is if you request a location for a detector (like GPS) and it has never gotten a location since its last boot up, it will return null. This is why it is usually better to request the updates first, which will cause the device to actively find one.

One technique is to find the location BEFORE you need it, then use getLastKnownLocation when you actually need it.

When using getLastKnownLocation it is always best to a) do your best to ensure that the location tracking device your using has already found a location as some point during this boot, and b) you check for nulls just in case.

As a side note, I would recommend checking the accuracy when getting new locations. It is very common that the first location found is not that as accurate as it could be, at the same time if you look for a period of time the LAST location found may not be as accurate as some other location found during the cycle. The key is use the GPS as little and as well controlled as possible, and double check your results.

Comment: Sorry I had to give the check to Ben, the requestLocationUpdates led me to the overall long run answer to my app.  I voted you up because your answer told me why it was not working. Wish I could give it to you both.  Thanks

Comment: No problem, I am pretty sure he answered first, I just wanted to clarify to further everyone's understanding. Teach a man to fish kinda thing.