# Location returns null (Android)

Tags: java, android

In my `onMapReady()` function i am trying to call a method like this:

```
onLocationChanged(getLastKnownLocation());
```

But if i start the Activity it crashes, and if i look in my console the location given as parameter from `getLastKnownLocation()` returns null.

Is there someone with some experience who can help me?

Here is my full class: (PechhulpActivity.java)
https://gist.github.com/soufyanekaddouri/c32d52fbb625800c4e40dc72c2cac55e

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map location returning null for android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608476/map-location-returning-null-for-android)

Comment: The answer doesn't work for me

Comment: You have turned on gps? Check with turned on and off.

Comment: Yes i have tried EVERYTHING to resolve the return null problem but again and again